# Oracle plsql object member function

Tags: oracle, object, plsql

Suppose an object was created as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type test_obj as object ( 
  item varchar2(20),
  constructor function test_obj return self as result
)

CREATE OR REPLACE type body test_obj as
  constructor function test_obj return self as result as
  begin
    self.item := 'xyz';
    return;
  end;
end;
```

Then it can be used in plsql as:

```
declare
  x test_obj; 
begin
  x:= test_obj();
end;
```

And is fine to create member functions and call them such as:

```
x test_obj := test_obj();
y number;    
y := x.somefunction('abc');
```

Can a member function be created to support this type of syntax:

```
x test_obj := test_obj();
y number;    
y := x('abc');
```

Comment: In other words, is there such a thing as a "default" member function? Not to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Because the object name is needed to call the constructor function, `x test_obj := test_obj();` oracle left the door open. Maybe one day!!!

Comment: in that scope, `x` is the name of a local variable (of type `test_obj`). It cannot be called as if it's a function. You can, however, create an alternative constructor function for `test_obj` so that you can `y := test_obj('abc');`

Comment: On the other hand, if you declare `x` to be an array (e.g. `table of test_obj`) indexed by VARCHAR2, you can then do `x('abc') := test_obj();` and `y := x('abc');` (if `y` is declared as another `test_obj`)

Comment: As I can understand you want to have something like a functor in C++, right ?

int operator()(char* p) { /* the code there */ }. PL/SQL does not allow to overload operators like +, -, /, (). In that sense seems there is no way to get functors similar to C++ ones.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, that is an idea I need to consider further... an associative array of test_obj...have to think if this helps....

Comment: Helps what? Perhaps instead of asking how to make a particular syntax work, you should state what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I am trying to simplify a particular coding construct which is used in almost everywhere.  I use an associative array to hold url parameters and wish to turn it into an object with some nice member functions. Yet at the same time, I want to access the var as `x('abc')` instead of `x.get('abc')`.

Comment: The approach that seems to be taken generally is for functions that need to be used extremely frequently, get names 1 character long - e.g. `x.g('abc')`.

Comment: Remember, the syntax is as much an aid to the developer 3 months later trying to read and understand your intention - `x('abc')` has a certain limited set of possible meanings in PL/SQL, so it *may* be a good thing that you can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that is possible.Doing So would be  destroying the very purpose of object oriented approach.
Since x is an instance of an object type you will have to invoke its methods using the dot notation.

BR,
TVS

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer because it is not possible to do in plsql.  I disagree that having a 'default member function' would destroy the purpose of the object oriented approach.